# Oracle Entity Framework 6 support for .net Framework 4 and VS 2010?

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, entity-framework-6, odp.net

I want to use entity framework 6 with an underlying Oracle database. I use Visual Studio 2010 (therefore .net framework 4). Oracle's [NuGet package for ODP.NET supporting EF 6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework/12.1.22), comes with an assembly built only for .net framework 4.5 (which is not supported in VS 2010).

Is there a way to have an ODP.NET assembly for .net4 supporting ef6? (or at least make the 4.5 assembly work in .net4 project?

If not, is there an alternative entity framework provider for Oracle database that is build for .net4?

Comment: Are you using "EF code first"? If so, .NET 4.5 is required ( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56485_01/win.121/e55744/InstallEntityReq.htm#ODPNT8263) . If you are using Model first or Database first, then .NET 4.0 is fine. Devart may offer a data provider that supports earlier versions of .NET with code first..

Comment: @ChristianShay yes I am using code first. I have no designer tools at all and my models are already defined. I want to switch the project from the previous ORM to Entity Framework. I think DevArt is the only alternative now.

Answer (score 1):

With "EF code first" .NET 4.5 is required ( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56485_01/win.121/e55744/InstallEntityReq.htm#ODPNT8263 ). If you are using Model first or Database first, then .NET 4.0 is fine. Devart may offer a data provider that supports .NET 4.0 with code first.